# Is this question about the pinhole camera model appropriate for us?

Tags: discussion, scope

There is a question on Stack Overflow, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8728759/need-some-help-to-understanding-the-formula, which is off topic there and is being considered for migration to Physics. Would it be appropriate on this site? I ask because, although the pinhole camera model itself could be classified under physics, the mathematical language which the question uses is decidedly *not* something we use in physics (as far as I know). The math seems to be fairly standard for computer image processing, and since the question is asking about interpreting that math, I believe it would be best treated at a site where computer image processing is on topic.

**What do you think?** Should this question, and more generally anything about the pinhole camera model regardless of what mathematical language it is phrased in, be on topic (or off topic) here?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see it as particularly good for Physics.SE: all the physics has already been done and the question is about the meaning of a particular mathematical notation that is very common in computer graphics circles.

Better on Math.SE, or just kept on Stack Overflow.